# Where in the Maven Standard Directory Layout should generated resources go?

Tags: maven

I'd like to generate some resources (JavaHelp search index in this case), but I can't seen to see where those generate files should go to get into the jar. I put them in target/generated-sources, but they are ignored. Should it be target/classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that generated-source directories are not automatically included in the jar. However, Intellj assumes there are and treats them as such, hence my confusion.

You need to use the Maven build helper plugin to fix this issue, for example:

https://github.com/alexec/javahelp-skeleton/blob/master/pom.xml

Answer (score 4):

- `/generated-sources` directory is used by various tools generating sources (*duh!*), like `xjc` or `wsdl2java`. This directory is later included in the compilation phase.
- `/target/classes` is everything that should be included in the final JAR, which answers your question. Also the contents of `/src/main/resources` is included, but this directory is typically part of version control and is not meant for generated artifacts.